# SQL: All rows of two tables merged together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine two different tables in a select statement where all the rows in the first table are matched with all the rows in the second table.  For example:

```
Table1
Table1_ID | FKey_Table2_ID
1           9
2           null

Table2
Table2_ID | Table2_Value
9           Yes
10          No
11          Maybe
```

Results needed:

```
Table1_ID | FKey_Table2_ID | Table2_ID | Table2_Value
1           9                9           Yes
1           null             10          No
1           null             11          Maybe
2           null             9           Yes
2           null             10          No
2           null             11          Maybe
```

Please note that the first row in Table1 has a key already assigned  from Table2.

Comment: Should the `FKey_Table2_ID` field for rows 2 and 3 be `9` rather than `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [cross join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and can be accomplished like this:

```
SELECT Table1_ID, FKey_Table2_ID, Table2_ID, Table2_Value
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2
```

Or more simply

```
SELECT Table1_ID, FKey_Table2_ID, Table2_ID, Table2_Value
FROM Table1, Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN
Table2
```